# Really quick question about the order of operations in the Lorentz force

Tags: electromagnetism, notation

I'm trying to calculate the Lorentz force for a particle in a uniform electric Field, E and magnetic field B.

The formulas is $$F=q(E+v\times B)$$

I'm just wondering what the order of operations is for this calculation. Do I calculate the cross product first then add or vice versa or does it even matter?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/41252/11127

Answer (score 4):

It does matter, and the product comes first. In general any sort of multiplication is understood to have higher precedence than any sort of addition. Thus
$$ \vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B} \equiv \vec{E} + (\vec{v} \times \vec{B}). $$